# How to add numbers next to the frame line using mdframed

Tags: mdframed, line, quotation, frame

I just came across the `mdframed` package and found it very useful. However, I would like to add numbers next to the frame line similar to the picture I attached (See red numbers, that's how I want it). Is there a way to do that?

This is the code I'm using to create the Churchill quote:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2,linecolor=black, innertopmargin=-.1em, innerbottommargin=0em, topline=false, rightline=false,bottomline=false, linenumber=1]
    
      \textit{A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.}
      \end{mdframed}
      \begin{center}
        {\textbf{\textit{--- Winston Churchill}}}
      \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: This how I want it to look like]

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.

Comment: Please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use `mdframed`, I propose a possible idea with `tikz`

- a first approach without `mdframed`
- a second with `mdframed` put in a box and then place the number.

There is undoubtedly much better to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670763/how-to-add-numbers-next-to-the-frame-line-using-mdframed
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<--- comment in the final doc
\usepackage{mdframed}%<--- comment in the final doc
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myquote}{m m m}{
    \noindent
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \if_case:w \int_mod:nn {#1} {2}%<--- test #1 even or odd
        \hfill
        \begin{tikzpicture}[outer~sep=4pt]
            %\node [draw] (T) {%<-- uncomment to see the box and comment the next line
            \node  (T) {%
                \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                    \textit{#2}
                \end{minipage}};
            \node at (T.south~east)[red,anchor=south~west]{\Large\bfseries #1};
            \draw [line~width=2pt](T.north~east) -- (T.south~east);
            \node at (T.south)[below]{%
                \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                    \begin{center}
                        \textbf{\textit{---~#3}}
                    \end{center}
                \end{minipage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \else: 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[outer~sep=4pt]
            %\node [draw] (T) {%
            \node  (T) {%
                \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                    \textit{#2}
                \end{minipage}};
            \node at (T.south~west)[red,anchor=south~east]{\Large\bfseries #1};
            \draw [line~width=2pt](T.north~west) -- (T.south~west);
            \node at (T.south)[below]{%
                \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                    \begin{center}
                        \textbf{\textit{---~#3}}
                    \end{center}
                \end{minipage}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \hfill\null 
    \fi:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
{\Large Without \texttt{mdframed}}

\bigskip
\myquote{1}{A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.}{Winston Churchill}

\myquote{2}{Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things you didn't do than by the ones you did. So throw off the bowlines, sail away from the safe harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails.}{Marc Twain}

\myquote{3}{\lipsum[1]}{Nobody}

{\Large With \texttt{mdframed}}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0)(T){\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2,linecolor=black, innertopmargin=-.1em, innerbottommargin=0em, topline=false, rightline=false,bottomline=false]
\par  
    \textit{A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{minipage}};
\node at (T.south west)[red,anchor=south east]{\Large\bfseries 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{center}
    {\textbf{\textit{--- Winston Churchill}}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

---

### Little factorization of the code (proposed by projetmbc)

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \quoteleftfill
\tl_new:N \quoterightfill

\tl_new:N \tagpos
\tl_new:N \anchorpos

\NewDocumentCommand{\myquote}{m m m}{
    \noindent

    \if_case:w \int_mod:nn {#1} {2}
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoteleftfill \hfill
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoterightfill {}

        \tl_gset:Nn \tagpos {east}
        \tl_gset:Nn \anchorpos {west}

    \else:
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoteleftfill {}
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoterightfill \hfill\null

        \tl_gset:Nn \tagpos {west}
        \tl_gset:Nn \anchorpos {east}
    \fi:

    \quoteleftfill

     \begin{tikzpicture}[outer~sep=4pt]
        %\node [draw] (T) {%<-- uncomment to see the box and comment the next line
        \node  (T) {%
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                \textit{#2}
            \end{minipage}};

        \node at (T.south~\tagpos)[red,anchor=south~\anchorpos]
            {\Large\bfseries #1};

        \draw [line~width=2pt](T.north~\tagpos) -- (T.south~\tagpos);

        \node at (T.south)[below]{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}%
                \begin{center}
                    \textbf{\textit{---~#3}}
                \end{center}
            \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \quoterightfill
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

---

### EDIT2,3 and 4: with the projetmbc's code and the comment of OP

- Width of the quote in option (0.8\linewidth by default)

**EDIT3**
The quote is pacer in a node.
[image]

With

```
\node at (T.south~\tagpos)[red,anchor=south~\anchorpos]
              {\Large\bfseries #2};
```

with `\tagpos` which contains either west or east (even or odd case)

We place the #2 which contains the number passed in the command `\myquote` at the bottom left or at the bottom right.

To get what you want, you have to remove south.

Replace `\node at (T.south~\tagpos)[red,anchor=south~\anchorpos]{\Large\bfseries #2};` by `\node at (T.\tagpos)[red,anchor=\anchorpos]{\Large\bfseries #2};`

**The code** EDIT4

```
        \documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670763/how-to-add-numbers-next-to-the-frame-line-using-mdframed
\usepackage{showframe}%<--- comment in the final doc
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \quoteleftfill
\tl_new:N \quoterightfill

\tl_new:N \tagpos
\tl_new:N \anchorpos

\NewDocumentCommand{\myquote}{O{0.8\linewidth} m m m}{
  % #1 the widtn (option)
  % #2 the number
  % #3 the quote
  % #4 the author
  %%%%%%%%%%%
    \noindent

    \if_case:w \int_mod:nn {#2} {2}
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoteleftfill \hfill
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoterightfill {}

        \tl_gset:Nn \tagpos {east}
        \tl_gset:Nn \anchorpos {west}

    \else:
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoteleftfill {}
        \tl_gset:Nn \quoterightfill \hfill\null

        \tl_gset:Nn \tagpos {west}
        \tl_gset:Nn \anchorpos {east}
    \fi:

    \quoteleftfill

    \begin{tikzpicture}[outer~sep=4pt]
        %\node [draw] (T) {%<-- uncomment to see the box and comment the next line
        \node  (T) {%
            \begin{minipage}{#1}%
                \textit{#3}
            \end{minipage}};

        \node at (T.\tagpos)[red,anchor=\anchorpos]
            {\Large\bfseries #2};

        \draw [line~width=2pt](T.north~\tagpos) -- (T.south~\tagpos);

        \node at (T.south)[below]{\textbf{\textit{---~#4}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \quoterightfill
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myquote{1}{A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.}{Winston Churchill}

\myquote{2}{Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things you didn't do than by the ones you did. So throw off the bowlines, sail away from the safe harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails.}{Marc Twain}
\end{document}
```

Remark The width of the node is by default 80% of the width of the line, you can choose another width by putting this parameter between square brackets (option). For example:

```
\myquote[5cm]{1}{A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.}`{Winston Churchill}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you! I'm not so familiar with coding in latex, but could you write down what is needed to change in the  script to make the numbers always aligned in the center of the line?

Comment: I allowed myself a small suggestion. I have edited your answer.

Comment: @projetmbc, nice factorisation

Comment: @Preben Honerød-Bentsen I'm not sure I understand the question. The number in the center and the quote, once on the left, once on the right?

Comment: @Preben Honerød-Bentsen, i propose a width of the quote in option

Comment: @pascal974 My apologies. As of now, the numbers will always be displayed at the bottom of the line next to the text. How do I change the main script for the numbers to always be displayed at the center of the line no matter how large the line is?

Comment: @Preben Honerød-Bentsen, Have you seen edit2 of my answer? Is this type of presentation? I added the image obtained with 0.47\linewidth

Comment: @Preben Honerød-Bentsen, another answer with table.

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution based in `tcolorbox` instead of `mdframed`. Following code proposes a `myquote` environment with a mandatory parameter corresponding to the cite's author. The box includes an automatically updated counter which is also automatically placed onto the left or right thank you to [`muzimuzhi Z`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671283/1952)'s help.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{myquote}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    flip title={sharp corners},
    title={--- #2},
    fonttitle=\bfseries\itshape,
    halign title=center,
    fontupper=\itshape,
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    left=3mm,
    right=3mm,
    toptitle=3mm,
    bottomtitle=3mm,
    /utils/if odd={\value{tcb@cnt@myquote}+1}%
        {overlay={%
            \draw[black, line width=2pt] (interior.north west)--(title.north west) node[left, red, midway]{\thetcbcounter};}}%
        {overlay={%
            \draw[black, line width=2pt] (interior.north east)--(title.north east) node[right, red, midway]{\thetcbcounter};}},
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{
  /utils/if odd/.code n args={3}{%
    \ifodd\numexpr#1\relax
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    \else
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    \fi
  }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{myquote}{Winston Churchill}
A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.
\end{myquote}

\begin{myquote}{Winston Churchill}
A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.
\end{myquote}

\begin{myquote}{Winston Churchill}
A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.
\end{myquote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with the number in the center of the line, use of a table.

- Use of a counter `mycnta` (see doc `tabularray` p.47)
- Each quote is on 3 lines,

  1 line with the number, the quote
  2 blank line
  3 the author
- manual management of vertical lines with `vline{3} = {1,7}{1pt}` (even quote), `vline{2} = {4}{1pt}` (odd quote)

**THE CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/670763/how-to-add-numbers-next-to-the-frame-line-using-mdframed
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    in the doc tabularray p.47
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}{\stepcounter{mycnta}\arabic{mycnta}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\setcounter{mycnta}{0}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[0.42\linewidth,valign=b]Q[1em,c,fg=red,font=\Large\bfseries]Q[0.42\linewidth,valign=b]},
    colsep=4pt,
    vline{3} = {1,7}{1pt},%<---   line 1 and 7 , vertical line colomn 3
    vline{2} = {4}{1pt},
    %hline{1,4,7}%<--- uncomment for the horizontal lines
}
    &\mycnta
    &
    A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool. It is a good thing for an uneducated man to read books of quotations.\\
    \\
    && \centering --- \textbf{\textit{Winston Churchill}}\\

    Twenty years from now you will be more disappointed by the things you didn't do than by the ones you did. So throw off the bowlines, sail away from the safe harbor. Catch the trade winds in your sails.
    &\mycnta\\
    \\
    \centering --- \textbf{\textit{Marc Twain}}\\
    &\mycnta
    &
    A fine quotation is a diamond in the hand of a man of wit and a pebble in the hand of a fool\dots\\
    \\
    && \centering --- \textbf{\textit{Nobody}}\\
\end{tblr} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was thinking more like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/prvns.png

The first option is good, but if I can change the code that the number are always aligned in the middle of the line, that would be great. Red numbers are for indication.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained more from the start. I added in EDIT3, some explanations.

Comment: I chose to name the node "T" (bad idea), it's the "N" on the picture.

Comment: The code you provided in the "Little factorization of the code (proposed by projetmbc)" has a perfect linewidth with the text, I only need the numbers to always be aligned in the center of the line. The code you provided "The code" has the correct number alignment, but the linewidth of the document is quite bad. And changing the default from 80% (low or higher) doesn't help. So if you could provide a code identical to the "factorization code" with number center aligned, that would be great.  Thank you for your patience and support so far.

Comment: This is with the "factorization code", https://i.stack.imgur.com/52u3Z.png . Here the linewidth of the document is perfect. If you could make a change so the numbers come in the position of the red numbers, that will solve it.

Comment: I put back in the EDIT4 code, the old version by modifying the vertical alignment of the number centered vertically with the quote.

Comment: Thank you very much, your support has been amazing. Problem solved.

Comment: You 're welcome.