# How to fix the style of a tcolorbox based on the tcbcounter?

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, conditionals

I would like to define a `tcolorbox` with an `auto counter`. The value of the counter will decide some part of the final style of the box. As an example, imagin that the background of the box alternates between blue and red for even or odd boxes.

There are several questions and answers about conditional styles for `TiKZ` nodes but I don't understand them and don't know how to apply to `tcolorbox`.

I know I can do it defining two different styles and manually applaying them, like in following code. But I prefer that LaTeX does the work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{oddbox}{
    colback=red!20,
    title=\thetcbcounter
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=oddbox]{evenbox}{
    colback=blue!20,
    title=\thetcbcounter
}


\begin{document}

\begin{oddbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{oddbox}

\begin{evenbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{evenbox}

\begin{oddbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{oddbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this new `pgfkeys` key

```tex
/utils/if odd={<num expr>}{<key lists if true>}{<key lists if false>}
```

you can use

```tex
/utils/if odd={\value{tcb@cnt@mybox}+1}{colback=red!20}{colback=blue!20}
```

to get the desired utility.

- When `<options>` in `\newtcolorbox[...]{mybox}{<options>}` are being processed at `\begin{mybox}`, counter wrappers `\tcbcounter` and `\thetcbcounter` are *not* updated or defined yet, nor the inner counter is stepped.  These actions all take place after processing `<options>`, see below.  Thus you have to use the inner counter `tcb@cnt@mybox` directly and add 1 to its value manually.

  Check use of `\tcolorbox[#6,options@for=#3]` in [`\__tcobox_new_tcolorbox:w` in `tcolorbox.sty` v5.1.1](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/blob/v5.1.1/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty#L2159-L2175) for more info.  Here style `options@for` holds `<options>` given to `\newtcolorbox`.  This processing order is required by keys like `/tcb/void`, which acts by overwriting `options@for` (through `options@for/.code=`).
- The key path prefix `/utils` is for wider range of use in all `pgfkeys` places, and is not the only option.

  If for example it's defined by `\tcbset{if odd/.code n args=...}`, then you can use `\newtcolorbox[...]{mybox}{if odd={}{}{}}`  but in non-`tcolorbox` places you have to use `/tcb/if odd` to get access to it.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}{
    /utils/if odd={\value{tcb@cnt@mybox}+1}% no spaces in between the three args
      {colback=red!20}{colback=blue!20},
    title=\thetcbcounter
}

\pgfkeys{
  /utils/if odd/.code n args={3}{%
    \ifodd\numexpr#1\relax
      \pgfkeysalso{#2}%
    \else
      \pgfkeysalso{#3}%
    \fi
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox} \lipsum[2][1-2] \end{mybox}
\begin{mybox} \lipsum[2][1-2] \end{mybox}
\begin{mybox} \lipsum[2][1-2] \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Guess there're similar questions already answered on this site. I'll try to find (one of) them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671328/1952